# valgrind invalid read of size 1 on execvp

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, execvp

I am using execvp for a mini shell project and valgrind showing me a huge memory leak on a single line: the line 263.

I have checked that i am not using none initialized variables and I am freeing my pointers and tabs. So i don't now where to look...

Someone see where the problem come from?

```
173 char **token_tab(char *line)
174 {
175   char **res_tab = NULL;
176   token *tok_tab = NULL;
177   token *tmp = NULL;
178   int cpt = 0;
179 
180   tok_tab = generate_token(line);
181   tmp = tok_tab;
182 
183   while (tmp != NULL)
184   {
185     cpt++;
186     tmp = tmp->next;
187   }
188 
189   res_tab = malloc(sizeof (char *) * cpt);
190 
191   tmp = tok_tab;
192 
193   for (int i = 0; i < cpt; ++i)
194   {
195     res_tab[i] = malloc(sizeof (char) * my_strlen(tmp->word));
196     my_strcpy(res_tab[i], tmp->word);
197     tmp = tmp->next;
198   }
199   res_tab[cpt - 1] = NULL;
200 
201   return res_tab;
202 }


     int exec_cmd(char **tab_word, pid_t pid)
259 {
260   int status = -5;
261   pid = fork();
262   if (pid == 0)
263     execvp(tab_word[0], tab_word);
264   else
265     wait(&status);
266 
267   free_double_char(tab_word);
268 
269   return WEXITSTATUS(status);
270 }

    minishell$ls
==22475== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22475==    at 0x400E91: main (minishell.c:357)
==22475== 
==22475== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22475==    at 0x400E69: main (minishell.c:358)
==22475== 
==22475== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22475==    at 0x401177: generate_token (new_lex.c:38)
==22475==    by 0x400AA4: token_tab (minishell.c:180)
==22475==    by 0x400EA7: main (minishell.c:361)
==22475== 
==22475== Invalid write of size 1
==22475==    at 0x402B6B: my_strcpy (my_strcpy.c:10)
==22475==    by 0x400B47: token_tab (minishell.c:196)
==22475==    by 0x400EA7: main (minishell.c:361)
==22475==  Address 0x51feb22 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==22475==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22475==    by 0x400B1B: token_tab (minishell.c:195)
==22475==    by 0x400EA7: main (minishell.c:361)
==22475== 
==22476== Invalid read of size 1
==22476==    at 0x4C2DBB0: __GI_strchr (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22476==    by 0x4EF8978: execvpe (execvpe.c:60)
==22476==    by 0x400CB1: exec_cmd (minishell.c:263)
==22476==    by 0x400EDE: main (minishell.c:366)
==22476==  Address 0x51feb22 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==22476==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22476==    by 0x400B1B: token_tab (minishell.c:195)
==22476==    by 0x400EA7: main (minishell.c:361)
==22476== 
==22476== Invalid read of size 1
==22476==    at 0x4C2E0F4: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22476==    by 0x4EF8AC4: execvpe (execvpe.c:101)
==22476==    by 0x400CB1: exec_cmd (minishell.c:263)
==22476==    by 0x400EDE: main (minishell.c:366)
==22476==  Address 0x51feb22 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==22476==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22476==    by 0x400B1B: token_tab (minishell.c:195)
==22476==    by 0x400EA7: main (minishell.c:361)
==22476== 
==22476== Invalid read of size 1
==22476==    at 0x4C2FF3E: __GI_memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22476==    by 0x4EF8B1D: execvpe (execvpe.c:126)
==22476==    by 0x400CB1: exec_cmd (minishell.c:263)
==22476==    by 0x400EDE: main (minishell.c:366)
==22476==  Address 0x51feb22 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==22476==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22476==    by 0x400B1B: token_tab (minishell.c:195)
==22476==    by 0x400EA7: main (minishell.c:361)
==22476== 
==22476== Syscall param execve(argv[i]) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==22476==    at 0x4EF8337: execve (execve.c:33)
==22476==    by 0x4EF8B88: execvpe (execvpe.c:149)
==22476==    by 0x400CB1: exec_cmd (minishell.c:263)
==22476==    by 0x400EDE: main (minishell.c:366)
==22476==  Address 0x51feb22 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==22476==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22476==    by 0x400B1B: token_tab (minishell.c:195)
==22476==    by 0x400EA7: main (minishell.c:361)
==22476==
```

thank you

Comment: Just asking, why you're not bothered about the other errors reported by valgrind? and BTW, on a lighter note, it's `leak`, not `leek`.

Comment: I am just treating them one by one

Comment: I now its a big peace of code... i am trying to make it cleaner, in fact this code doesn't work all times, if i am making an echo command 2 times it starting to print bad characters...

Comment: "Invalid read" != "Memory leak". I guess that the array `tab_word` is not properly initialized.

Comment: how is the variable 'tmp' defined?

Comment: in C, 'sizeof(char)' is always 1, so that expression in the malloc parameter has no effect and just clutters the code

Comment: Suggest using a debugger to step through the code to see what is actually going on.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are not allocating for last `'\0'` character for the strings.

The line

```
res_tab[i] = malloc(sizeof (char) * my_strlen(tmp->word));
```

should allocate 1 more char

```
res_tab[i] = malloc(sizeof (char) * (my_strlen(tmp->word) + 1) );
```

I'm assuming here that the `my_strlen()` is similar to `strlen()` and does not count `'\0'` in the length.

Comment: i tried to malloc res_tab with (my_strlen(tmp->word) + 1) and after that,
res_tab[i][my_strlen(tmp->word)] = '\0'
but it didn't worked...

Comment: @threejay It should be your my_strcpy which copy the '\0'

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory leak. You overwrite the last malloc to res_tab[cpt-1] with NULL without freeing first. If the last token is not supposed to be skipped:

```
res_tab = malloc(sizeof (char *) * (cpt+1));
```

and

```
res_tab[cpt] = NULL;
```